# Paypal payment failed with saved card

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

#SOLVED [from first comment answer]

I am try to build paypal advance payment and card save during payment with nodejs. I successfully build paypal advance payment and store card in vault. but the problem is while I try to pay with previously saved card, it fails. Order is created successfully then the error occurred.

checkout html (ejs)

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/css/cardfields.css" />
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=buttons,hosted-fields&client-id=<%= clientId %>"
    data-client-token="<%= clientToken %>"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="paypal-button-container" class="paypal-button-container"></div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <form id="card-form">
      <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
      <div id="card-number" class="card_field"></div>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <div>
          <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
          <div id="expiration-date" class="card_field"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
          <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
          <div id="cvv" class="card_field"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="card-holder-name">Name on Card</label>
      <input type="text" id="card-holder-name" name="card-holder-name" autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="card holder name" />
      <div>
        <label for="card-billing-address-street">Billing Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-street" name="card-billing-address-street" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="street address" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="card-billing-address-unit">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-unit" name="card-billing-address-unit" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="unit" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-city" name="card-billing-address-city" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="city" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-state" name="card-billing-address-state" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="state" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-zip" name="card-billing-address-zip" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="zip / postal code" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="card-billing-address-country" name="card-billing-address-country" autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="country code" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="save" name="save">
        <label for="save">Save your card</label>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
      <button value="submit" id="submit" class="btn">Pay</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
paypal
  .Buttons({
    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch("/api/orders", {
        method: "post"
        // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information
        // like product ids or amount
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((order) => order.id);
    },
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch(`/api/orders/${data.orderID}/capture`, {
        method: "post",
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((orderData) => {
          // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
          console.log(
            "Capture result",
            orderData,
            JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2)
          );
          const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
          alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}

            See console for all available details
          `);
          // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
          // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
          // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
          // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
        });
    },
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");

// If this returns false or the card fields aren't visible, see Step #1.
if (paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()) {
  let orderId;

  // Renders card fields
  paypal.HostedFields.render({
    // Call your server to set up the transaction
    createOrder: () => {
      return fetch("/api/orders", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          save: document.querySelector('#save').checked,
          card_name: document.getElementById("card-holder-name").value,
          billing_address: {
            address_line_1: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-street").value,
            address_line_2: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-unit").value,
            admin_area_2: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-city").value,
            admin_area_1: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-state").value,
            postal_code: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-zip").value,
            country_code: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-country").value
          }
        })
        // use the "body" param to optionally pass additional order information like
        // product ids or amount.
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((orderData) => {
          console.log("==============>create order response<==============");
          console.log(orderData);
          orderId = orderData.id; // needed later to complete capture
          return orderData.id;
        });
    },
    styles: {
      ".valid": {
        color: "green",
      },
      ".invalid": {
        color: "red",
      },
    },
    fields: {
      number: {
        selector: "#card-number",
        placeholder: "4111 1111 1111 1111",
      },
      cvv: {
        selector: "#cvv",
        placeholder: "123",
      },
      expirationDate: {
        selector: "#expiration-date",
        placeholder: "MM/YY",
      },
    },
  }).then((cardFields) => {
    document.querySelector("#card-form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      cardFields
        .submit({
          save: document.querySelector('#save').checked,
          // Cardholder's first and last name
          cardholderName: document.getElementById("card-holder-name").value,
          // Billing Address
          billingAddress: {
            // Street address, line 1
            streetAddress: document.getElementById(
              "card-billing-address-street"
            ).value,
            // Street address, line 2 (Ex: Unit, Apartment, etc.)
            extendedAddress: document.getElementById(
              "card-billing-address-unit"
            ).value,
            // State
            region: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-state").value,
            // City
            locality: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-city")
              .value,
            // Postal Code
            postalCode: document.getElementById("card-billing-address-zip")
              .value,
            // Country Code
            countryCodeAlpha2: document.getElementById(
              "card-billing-address-country"
            ).value,
          },
        })
        .then(() => {
          fetch(`/api/orders/${orderId}/capture`, {
            method: "post",
          })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((orderData) => {
              console.log("==============>capture order response<==============");
              console.log(orderData);
              // Two cases to handle:
              //   (1) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
              //   (2) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you
              // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
              // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
              const errorDetail =
                Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
              if (errorDetail) {
                var msg = "Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.";
                if (errorDetail.description)
                  msg += "\n\n" + errorDetail.description;
                if (orderData.debug_id) msg += " (" + orderData.debug_id + ")";
                return alert(msg); // Show a failure message
              }
              // Show a success message or redirect
              alert("Transaction completed!");
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("Payment could not be captured! " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    });
  });
} else {
  // Hides card fields if the merchant isn't eligible
  document.querySelector("#card-form").style = "display: none";
}
```

paypal-api.js

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

// set some important variables
const { CLIENT_ID, APP_SECRET } = process.env;
const base = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";

// call the create order method
export async function createOrder(body) {
  const purchaseAmount = "100.00"; // TODO: pull prices from a database
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: body ? JSON.stringify({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: purchaseAmount,
          },
        },
      ],
      payment_source: {
        card: {
          name: body.card_name,
          billing_address: body.billing_address,
          attributes: {
            vault: {
              store_in_vault: 'ON_SUCCESS'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }) : undefined,
  });

  return handleResponse(response);
}

// capture payment for an order
export async function capturePayment(orderId) {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders/${orderId}/capture`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  return handleResponse(response);
}

// generate access token
export async function generateAccessToken() {
  const auth = Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET).toString("base64");
  const response = await fetch(`${base}/v1/oauth2/token`, {
    method: "post",
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
    },
  });
  const jsonData = await handleResponse(response);
  return jsonData.access_token;
}

// generate client token
export async function generateClientToken() {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const response = await fetch(`${base}/v1/identity/generate-token`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Accept-Language": "en_US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      customer_id: 'kxIaZbNwOZ'
    })
  });
  const jsonData = await handleResponse(response);
  return jsonData.client_token;
}

async function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
    return response.json();
  }

  const errorMessage = await response.text();
  throw new Error(errorMessage);
}
```

server.js

```
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import * as paypal from "./paypal-api.js";

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

// render checkout page with client id & unique client token
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
  try {
    const clientToken = await paypal.generateClientToken();
    res.render("checkout", { clientId, clientToken });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

// create order
app.post("/api/orders", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const order = await paypal.createOrder(req.body);
    res.json(order);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

// capture payment
app.post("/api/orders/:orderID/capture", async (req, res) => {
  const { orderID } = req.params;
  try {
    const captureData = await paypal.capturePayment(orderID);
    res.json(captureData);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

app.listen(8888, () => console.log("App Started."));
```

Error:

```
{
    "err": "Error: Shipping address requested for card payment\n...",
    "timestamp": "1673098647388",
    "referer": "www.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "sdkCorrelationID": "04103b485b692",
    "sessionID": "uid_82aff76087_mtm6mzu6mzk",
    "clientID": "AUUbkZiQ1akU7ChP0UxbWN9U8-wR0pYmOUF8gzkXtsrcbn9GXDLB0fjOT14vG-rvWYwGmM7Lzj8LDK-C",
    "env": "sandbox",
    "buttonSessionID": "uid_05c2d7e1ec_mtm6mzc6mtq",
    "buttonCorrelationID": "a17486c9208f5",
    "time": "1673098647388",
    "user_id": "uid_05c2d7e1ec_mtm6mzc6mtq",
    "token": "2VY75292WT2863902"
}
```

```
Uncaught Error: Shipping address requested for card payment
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?sdkVersion=5.0.344&style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.menuPlacement=below&components.0=buttons&components.1=hosted-fields&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jb21wb25lbnRzPWJ1dHRvbnMsaG9zdGVkLWZpZWxkcyZjbGllbnQtaWQ9QVVVYmtaaVExYWtVN0NoUDBVeGJXTjlVOC13UjBwWW1PVUY4Z3prWHRzcmNibjlHWERMQjBmak9UMTR2Ry1ydldZd0dtTTdMemo4TERLLUMiLCJhdHRycyI6eyJkYXRhLXVpZCI6InVpZF9laWVpbXFteW9tY3F4am1xeWd4dGxsZWlld2FvcmIifX0&clientID=AUUbkZiQ1akU7ChP0UxbWN9U8-wR0pYmOUF8gzkXtsrcbn9GXDLB0fjOT14vG-rvWYwGmM7Lzj8LDK-C&clientAccessToken=A21AALuiYv6v0yKLvGRKk4KoMModxjNd_Ph185k19xRLIjbptX_pGsMmYPvM9pTdyuKBwJbDm33J9zeRmkwl9_FbdGY1WtwIw&sdkCorrelationID=04103b485b692&storageID=uid_e93c1270fe_mtm6mzu6mzk&sessionID=uid_82aff76087_mtm6mzu6mzk&buttonSessionID=uid_05c2d7e1ec_mtm6mzc6mtq&env=sandbox&buttonSize=huge&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&experiment.enableVenmo=false&experiment.enableVenmoAppLabel=false&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&renderedButtons.0=paypal&renderedButtons.1=paylater&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=false&experience=&allowBillingPayments=true:1492:261589
    at n.dispatch (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?sdkVersion=5.0.344&style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.menuPlacement=below&components.0=buttons&components.1=hosted-fields&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jb21wb25lbnRzPWJ1dHRvbnMsaG9zdGVkLWZpZWxkcyZjbGllbnQtaWQ9QVVVYmtaaVExYWtVN0NoUDBVeGJXTjlVOC13UjBwWW1PVUY4Z3prWHRzcmNibjlHWERMQjBmak9UMTR2Ry1ydldZd0dtTTdMemo4TERLLUMiLCJhdHRycyI6eyJkYXRhLXVpZCI6InVpZF9laWVpbXFteW9tY3F4am1xeWd4dGxsZWlld2FvcmIifX0&clientID=AUUbkZiQ1akU7ChP0UxbWN9U8-wR0pYmOUF8gzkXtsrcbn9GXDLB0fjOT14vG-rvWYwGmM7Lzj8LDK-C&clientAccessToken=A21AALuiYv6v0yKLvGRKk4KoMModxjNd_Ph185k19xRLIjbptX_pGsMmYPvM9pTdyuKBwJbDm33J9zeRmkwl9_FbdGY1WtwIw&sdkCorrelationID=04103b485b692&storageID=uid_e93c1270fe_mtm6mzu6mzk&sessionID=uid_82aff76087_mtm6mzu6mzk&buttonSessionID=uid_05c2d7e1ec_mtm6mzc6mtq&env=sandbox&buttonSize=huge&fundingEligibility=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
```

Expecting the payment success

Comment: Set the `shipping_address` key in the payment_source and/or in the application_context to SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS or NO_SHIPPING

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).